# Testing React component with Enzyme Jest finding HTML element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component called `Typography` that takes a `variant` prop and renders an element accordingly.

**Typography.js**

Omitting a lot for brevity

```
import { StyledH1, ... } from './Typography.styles';

const variantMapping = {h1: StyledH1, ...};

const Typography = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const Component = variantMapping[props.variant] ? variantMapping[props.variant] : 'span';

  return <Component {...props}>{children}</Component>;
};
```

So I've tried numerous ways to get a working test. Right now I'm trying to pass `variant="h1"`, get back the following markup `<h1 class="..styled component what nots...">...</h1>` and verify an `<h1>` renders

**Typography.spec.js**

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Typography from '.';

describe('<Typography />', () => {
  it('renders H1', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Typography variant="h1" />);
    const elem = wrapper;
    console.log(elem.debug());
    expect(wrapper.find('h1')).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

So running the debugger I get back

```
console.log components/Typography/Typography.spec.js:9
    <Typography variant="h1" bold={false} transform={{...}} small={false}>
      <Typographystyles__StyledH1 variant="h1" bold={false} transform={{...}} small={false}>
        <StyledComponent variant="h1" bold={false} transform={{...}} small={false} forwardedComponent={{...}} forwardedRef={{...}}>
          <h1 transform={{...}} className="Typographystyles__StyledH1-sc-1n6ui1k-0 bvGdAG" />
        </StyledComponent>
      </Typographystyles__StyledH1>
    </Typography>
```

So I changed up the element variable to find the h1 element 
`const elem = wrapper.find('h1');`

And debugger returns

```
console.log components/Typography/Typography.spec.js:9
<h1 transform={{...}} className="Typographystyles__StyledH1-sc-1n6ui1k-0 bvGdAG" />
```

I'm not sure if this is the right approach, just a matter of trying to get at least 1 reasonably passing test.

At this point every `expect` statement I write comes back with an error or failure

- `expect(elem).to.have.lengthOf(1);` TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined
- `expect(elem.contains('h1')).to.equal(true);` TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined
- `expect(elem.contains('h1')).toEqual(true);` expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Have tried a few more options and nothing is working out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it looks like my assertions, using Enzyme, on `expect` are not setup. Upon reading the Enzyme docs further my setup is only using the Adapter allowing for easier rendering/mounting of components. I do not have the ability to use the Enzyme assertions from the docs because they are not installed. Rather to answer this particular problem I have to use the Jest assertions.

```
describe('<Typography />', () => {
  it('renders h1', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Typography variant="h1" />);
    const elem = wrapper.find('h1');
    expect(elem.length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect

Answer (score 2):

Enzyme full dom mounting:

[.find(selector) => ReactWrapper](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html#findselector--reactwrapper) returns a wrapper, not a boolean

```
it('renders H1', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<Typography variant="h1" />);
  const elem = wrapper;
  console.log(elem.debug());
  expect(elem.find('h1')).to.have.length(1);
});
```

[.contains(nodeOrNodes) => boolean](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/contains.html#containsnodeornodes--boolean) - Here's a link to the [common gotchas](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/contains.html#common-gotchas), notably that it expects a react element, not a html element or CSS selector

Comment: Thanks for the response unfortunately this doesn't work either.

Debugs to the first debugger statement in the question with the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined`

Comment: I see. I just use mostly jest matchers anyway. `jest-extended` is also a nice package as well. It's got me through most of my testing needs.